# Android: Developing Plugins for media sharing

Tags: android, dlna

We are developing plugins which convert media file as the source and convert in to other format that can be used by DLNA compatible device in android.

Any help on how to deal with media and its file format and convert into DLNA file format..

Any idea will be appreciable...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several containers and codecs supported by DLNA, most of which can be created with FFmpeg.

Specs: http://www.dlna.org/industry/why_dlna/key_components/media_format/

Now do you plan to do the conversion on the device or will a server be involved? There are several servers on this approved / supported list: http://www.rbgrn.net/content/21-how-to-choose-dlna-media-server-windows-mac-os-x-or-linux

If you plan to do conversion on the device, there are ports of FFmpeg that run on Android but your mileage will vary of course.

Comment: here look at my requirement if u have can guide me 1> Source : Stream or Media  2> Target : DLNA complianted device  3> My plug in will able to convert media to UPnP/DLNA format. This plugin will be available from the the server.  4> My app : Will connect source to target...this plugin will be available for download from server...

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in using Kik API for sharing rich content and media with other mobile app users. You can build your app on top of Kik Messenger and use Kik's own transport, infrastructure and userbase to share content from your mobile app. This API is available for Android and iPhone, and in simpler scenarios it takes only about 5 lines of code to integrate. There is more info on Kik API website: http://www.kik.com/dev and http://apiblog.kik.com

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers behind Kik API :)